# How to reinstall and completely wipe out Windows and the old install of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I installed Ubuntu and it kept windows but I lost things in both, so I downloaded Ubuntu again through different means and the install is going slow but it's doing better than the first install.

I want to know if I can get rid of Windows and the old install of Ubuntu during this installation, so all I have on my computer is the new Ubuntu installation that is currently running?

Answer (score 1):

Select the option to use the entire disk during the installation. Beware that this will erase your entire harddisk! So please make 100% sure that you have backups of everything that you need, especially things like documents, pictures, music, etc. before you proceed.

I would recommend using a separate partition for your home directory (or a separate disk as stated by the post below) because it makes backup and reinstall so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Like the previous poster mentioned, be sure you have backups of everything you want to keep as this will format the entire hard disk.  For this reason, I recommend running with two physical hard disks.  One is used for the operating system, and the other is used for all your personal files.  It's much easier to do things like installations, etc.

Comment: What do I do with the public (non-personal) files? Third hard disk?

Comment: or a separate partition on the second physical disk.  or just be sure you know where they all are on the second disk and you can select which files and folders to share on your network and share locally via permissions.

Comment: oh, and eventually with some practice you'll want to select "do something else" or whatever it is on the installation choices that brings up the mapping of your hard disks and partitions so you can decide where everything goes.